# CMake is slow to generate makefiles

Tags: cmake

When I run CMake to build the [Theia library](https://github.com/kip622/Theia) it is very slow to generate makefiles with CMake (takes 1-2 minutes easily). The project itself has many source files, but I am wondering if there is a way to speed up the makefile generation to be faster. Any ideas?

Comment: use `strace` to check whats going on under the hood.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I noticed that cmake is faster at generating ninja files than make files 9s vs 60s in my case.

Comment: I've added a bounty to this related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436945/cmake-rebuild-cache-for-just-a-subdirectory?lq=1